# Silverlight 3 with WCF RIA services with VS2010 possible?

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

Got confused with microsoft website descriptions. or May be the google search results just confused me. My company wants to use silverlight for a line of business application but doesnt want to go with .NET 4.0.

Can we develop SL3 applications with WCF RIA services 1.0 using .NET 3.5 with VS2008?

Can we develop SL3 applications with WCF RIA services 1.0 using .NET 3.5 with VS2010?

Can we develop SL4 applications with WCF RIA services 1.0 using .NET 3.5 with VS2010?

My only problem is I am not allowed to install .NET 4.0 on the web server. I can request users to install SL4.0 plugin if required. I can also put a request to buy VS2010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sure can, just [visit this link](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/) to get started. Note that RIA services is still in beta though.

Comment: Thank you Slugster. I tried it with VS2010 beta by selecting .NET 3.5 as target framework. I wasnt given an option to enable .NET ria services for the projects. The Checkbox to enable .NET ria services is disabled. There is no DomainService class in the VS2010 templates for .NET 3.5

Comment: Seems like WCF RIA services installation package for VS2010 Beta 2 & VS2008 is not the same. With VS2010 Beta 2, we cant enable ria services for .NET 3.5 framework. Is there any work around/ solution to use VS2010, .NET 3.5 & .NET ria services?